# XmlParser Error while rendering a Dynamic Jasper report in Java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I need create a report with Columns added dynamically, So i choose Dynamic Report version 5.3.2 to achieve this, but there is problem while rendering the report. i have an Exception i dont know what's wrong, it's about xml parser or something like but i don't really know. I use jdk 1.8.2.0 and Netabeans 11.0 as IDE, here is the excpetion

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.<init>(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:149)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.getInstance(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:131)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.ensureFontExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:80)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:57)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:134)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:86)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:114)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:82)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:251)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:272)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:156)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:145)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:758)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:1074)
    at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(DynamicJasperHelper.java:244)
    at ar.com.fdvs.dj.core.DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(DynamicJasperHelper.java:220)
    at com.gepa.views.principal.PrincipalScreenx.rapportPerformanceActionAction(PrincipalScreenx.java:6307)
    at com.gepa.views.principal.PrincipalScreenx$85.actionPerformed(PrincipalScreenx.java:3166)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Here is my code for creating the dynamic report

```
                     FastReportBuilder drb = new FastReportBuilder();
        drb.addColumn("State", "state", String.class.getName(),30)
            .addColumn("Branch", "branch", String.class.getName(),30)
                        .addColumn("Product Line", "productLine", String.class.getName(),50)
            .addColumn("Item", "item", String.class.getName(),50)
            .addColumn("Item Code", "id", Long.class.getName(),30,true)
            .addColumn("Quantity", "quantity", Long.class.getName(),60,true)
            .addColumn("Amount", "amount", Float.class.getName(),70,true)
            .addGroups(2)
            .setTitle("November " + 2021 +" sales report")
            .setSubtitle("This report was generated at " + new Date())
            .setPrintBackgroundOnOddRows(true)          
            .setUseFullPageWidth(true);
                
                      drb.addGlobalFooterVariable(drb.getColumn(4), DJCalculation.COUNT, null, new DJValueFormatter() {
  
              public String getClassName() {
                  return String.class.getName();
              }
  
  
              public Object evaluate(Object value, Map fields, Map variables,   Map parameters) {
                  return (value == null ? "0" : value.toString()) + " Clients";
              }
          });
             List rowsDataList = new ArrayList();


               DynamicReport   dr = drb.build();
               JasperPrint finalreport =  DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dr,new ClassicLayoutManager(), rowsDataList);
               JasperViewer.viewReport(finalreport);
               
       

                 }catch(Exception e)
                 {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
```

I don't know if it's cause by a missing dependancy or a conflict but it's not working,  Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

looks like your project is using a old version of the JAXP (Locate and uninstall the plugin that loads the outdated implementation of the Java API for XML Processing (JAXP), e.g., Xerces 2.6.)

I found this info that might help: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036082251-Pipeline-Maven-Integration-fails-due-to-java-lang-AbstractMethodError?page=21